# Codeigniter 3 application: redirect to a certain controller if there are no tables in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic blog application with **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and **Bootstrap 4**.

I use migration files (`001_create_authors.php` up to `005_create_comments.php`) to automatically create the necessary database tables.

The controller running the migrations is at

> application/controllers/Migrate.php

It has the flowing code:

```
class Migrate extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->library('migration');

    if($this->migration->current() === FALSE)
    {
      show_error($this->migration->error_string());
    }
    else {
      echo 'Migration executed';
    }
  }
}
```

The default controller is the `Posts` controller, as the `routes.php` file shows: `$route['default_controller'] = 'posts';`

I would like the `Posts` controller to redirect to the `Migrate` one, if *there are no tables in the database*. Does Codeigniter have a method to determine if there are no tables? How shall I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/metadata.html

```
if (count($this->db->list_tables()) == 0) {
    redirect(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result this exact way:

In the Posts controller (default):

```
public function index() {
  // Create all the database tables if there are none
  // by redirecting to the Migrations controller
    if (count($this->db->list_tables()) == 0) {
       redirect('migrate');
     }
     // More code
}
```

In the Migrate controller:

```
class Migrate extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->library('migration');

    if($this->migration->current() === FALSE)
    {
      show_error($this->migration->error_string());
    }
    else {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('tables_created', "All the required database tables have been created. You can now register.");
      redirect('/');
    }
  }
}
```